# cuda: how is shared memory laid out on the bank?

Tags: caching, cuda, gpu-shared-memory

I have understanding of banks, bank width, and bank conflict. But I don't understand how multiple statically allocated shared memory is laid out through the banks.

If I assume:
4 bytes of bank width
32 banks
sizeof(int) == 4 bytes

Then how would **shared1** and **shared2** be **laid out throughout the banks**? Would shared 2 be placed immidiately succeeding shared1 ( i.e. the last value of shared1 is stored in bank 0 and the first value of shared2 is stored in bank 1 )? or would the end of shared1 be padded (i.e. the last value of shared1 is stored in bank 0 and banks 1 ~ 31 are padded, and shared 2 starts from bank 0 of the next row )?

```
__device__ void main( void ){
    __shared__ int shared1[33];
    __shared__ int shared2[31];
    ...
}
```

Would this behavior be different if shared2 is allocated in a nested function?:

```
__device__ void main( void ){
    __shared__ int shared1[33];
    fun<<1, 1>>();
    ...
}

__device__ void fun( void ){
    __shared__ int shared2[31]
}
```

Lastly, does the order of declaration change the layout of shared memory?

Comment: There is no shared memory anywhere in any of the code in your question.

Comment: @talonmies Edited my post. Thanks for the heads up

Comment: Should be contiguous. As fas as I know NVCC aligns arrays in shared memory to a single element, in your case 4 bytes.

Comment: None of the questions or concerns here will affect the presence or absence of bank conflicts when you access these arrays in your code, with the possible exception of bizarre cases where you are using swizzled pointer-indirect access.  The presence or absence of bank conflicts can be entirely determined by inspecting your code, without requiring any knowledge of layout.  And whether you are accessing `shared1`, or `shared2`, such an access will be entirely unaffected for the purposes of bank conflicts by any decisions the compiler makes about array starting positions/layout in shared memory.

Comment: This conclusion is predicated on two ideas: 1. For a given array, consecutive elements are located consecutively in memory.  2.  shared memory banks are arranged consecutively in memory.  Therefore, for any warp-wide access to a particular array, the starting position of that array with respect to the banks is irrelevant.